# Vertical Bars in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, web

How would I go about constructing vertical bars, all adjacent to each other (touching) from the left side of the page to the middle (all the same size in width)?

Comment: Just to clarify, what kind of vertical bars are you looking for?  Columns of content?  Separate columns in your layout?  Or do you mean vertical lines in the background?  Sorry, but I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for.

Comment: You might use images for that purpose.

Comment: Rolled back the change to "delete post" gibberish, there's no reason to do that and it's not fair to people who took the time to give an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do the trick for you:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="bar green"></div>
    <div class="bar greener"></div>
    <div class="bar greenest"></div>
    <div class="bar greenerest"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS to go with it:

```
html, body, #wrapper, .bar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 50%;
}

.bar {
    float: left;
    width: 25%; /* must never add up to more than 100% */
}

.green {
    background-color: #a8ff00;
}

.greener {
    background-color: #7ad800;
}

.greenest {
    background-color: #3eb603;
}

.greenerest {
    background-color: #2c7e03;
}
```

You can see it [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/KwEmz/1/).